# Isolate variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a complex equation that when broken down to parts simplifies to the following equation.

$ay = zy + b$

I need to have only $a$ and $b$ on one side and only $z$ and $y$ on the other. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this. I understand that there might be some high level math involved, but that is not an issue.

As a secondary reference, here is the original equation.

### $$w = .658^\frac{Ax^2}{B\pi^2y^2}AzC$$

Basically I need to get the $w$ and $x$ isolated from the other variables. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all constants if that helps.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind requiring the variables to be on specific sides?

Comment: I am trying to create a table that will tell me the failure point of a compression member, given it's profile, but not given length. Then calculate that failure value given the Length and compression force. This will allow me to perform a table search instead of re-running calculations across the entire table when ever the compression force or length of the member changes.

Comment: Those two variable represent the length of a compression member, and the compression force. I need to calculate failure solely based on profile, and also failure solely based on length and force, then compare them.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you mean. In any case, your equation just boils down to $$w=p e^{q x^2}$$ Where $p=ACz$ and $q=\frac{A}{\pi^2 B y^2} \ln(0.658)$

Comment: That still doesn't isolate $w$ and $x$ from the rest of the variables. That is the problem I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: So you can calculate the failure point of a steel compression member with the following equation $$w = .658^\frac{Ax^2}{B\pi^2y^2}AzC$$ where W is the maximum force it can resist, X is the length of the member, a,b, and c are properties of steel, and Z a property of a given steel profile.

I know the length of my compression member, and how much force it will experience (w and x), and I need to select the cheapest profile that will work.

Comment: I can order my list of profile from cheapest to most expensive, but this would mean calculating failure point of each profile, then comparing it to my force. I believe it should be possible to calculate a minimum failure point based on length and compression force, then simply look for a profile that has that failure point, regardless of the length of the beam. Then it becomes a simple table search.

Comment: Z is a property of the profile. I want to calculate a failure point for the profile that is length agnostic. This is due to the fact that I run hundreds of calculations a second already for a structure optimization. Having to iterate through a table with 1000+ plus entries every time I change the length would not be ideal